# XML - list of elements fixed types - proper schema

Tags: xml, xsd

How to write xsd schema such that it will validate following xml:

```
<myElement>
   <dogs>
     <dog> .... </dog>
     <dog> .... </dog>
     ....
   </dogs>

   <cats>
     <cat> .... </cat>
     <cat> .... </cat>
     ....
   </cats>

</myElement>
```

All of these types are ready in my case, I mean elements: `myElement, dog, cat`, the thing that I have a problem is creating two lists: `cats` and `dogs`.  How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema, you can add something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="catsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="cat" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="cats" type="catsType" />
```

This creates a complex type named `catsType` which states that its content is a sequence of one or more `cat` elements. Next an element with name `cats` of that type is defined. This element can then be referred to, for example in your definition of `myElement`. Or, you can define an element with a chosen name anywhere and state that its type is `catsType`.

It's also possible to just provide the definition in-line, which is okay if you don't need to re-use it outside of the `cats` element:

```
<xs:element name="cats">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="cat" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The `cats` element can now be used as before, but the definition is local to it.

What you decide to do in-line and what separately depends on which definitions or elements occur in more than one place, and is also a bit of a matter of style. I prefer to avoid "arrows" in my XML schemas by nesting definitions too deep. Defining things separately from where they are used also makes later refactoring easier if it's needed.